# how to store and restore an array in cookie, session or local storage in jquery for specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage, session-storage

How to store the content of an array in cookies, session or local storage, and then again restore or push into an array to use as regular. It should be set for specific time and after that time, it should not be restoring values.

**Edit**
I tried this for cookies need for local-storage and session-storage and with array

```
var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 30;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

Comment: No code, no help! What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cookie:

```
 var date = new Date();
 var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000)); //Expires in 30 minutes
 $.cookie("cookieName", cars, { expires: date });
 alert( $.cookie("cookieName") );
```

For local storage:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
localStorage.setItem( 'name', cars );
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
var date = new Date();
localStorage.setItem( 'expiretime', date );
if(localStorage.getItem( 'expiretime' ) > Date()) {
    alert(localStorage.getItem( 'name' ));
}
```

For session:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
$.session.set("name", cars);
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
var date = new Date();
$.session.set("expiretime", date);
if($.session.get( 'expiretime' ) > Date()) {
    alert($.session.get( 'name' ));
}
```

Comment: go to get them back

Comment: @QadeerMangrio what do you mean?